# airtight bin for bulk grain

Tags: equipment

We are having a really hard time finding a truly airtight bin large enough to keep at least 50 lbs of bulk grain in. Does anyone have any suggestions? We keep our grains in the shed and want to keep out mice and bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an even better solution than a locking trash can. Sometimes mice can even squeeze through the tiny openings or chew through the edges of a locking trash can. My husband and I recently started using large pet food containers designed for horse food. It's made from a very thick plastic that even rodents cannot chew through. The lid screws tight for an air tight seal and the plastic is food grade/non BPA.

Gamma2 Vittles Vault Stackable Pet Food Storage
[image: Gamma2 Vittles Vault Stackable Pet Food Storage]

https://www.chewy.com/gamma2-vittles-vault-stackable-pet/dp/101389

Answer (score 2):

I use a large rubbermaid trash can with a tight lid. I put in a thick construction style trash bag. I can fit 100lbs of grain easy. I then twist the trash bag, clip it shut, and put the locking lid on the trash can. I have had grain for two years in it without it going bad.

Answer (score 1):

[Homebrew Finds has a nice roundup of all the options](http://www.homebrewfinds.com/2015/04/storage-options-base-grain-specialty-grain-and-dme-buckets-and-gamma-seal-lids-on-sale.html).  I use food-grade 5 gallon pails and Gamma lids that I got from Menards (the cheapest way to go that route, if you have a Menards nearby), and I've never had problems with bugs.

Comment: are 5 gallon buckets big enough to store 50lbs of grain?

Comment: 2 5 gallon pails with Gamma Lids are almost large enough to store 50# of 2 Row (you'll end up with about 1-2 pounds of grain left over), and are large enough to store 50# of wheat with a little space left over.

Answer (score 1):

I have used old 5gal plastic fermentation bins, with some gaffer tape over the airlock hole. This has worked well for me.

Comment: are 5 gallon buckets big enough to store 50lbs of grain?

Answer (score 1):

5-6 gal buckets w/lids work great.  I saw some large ZipLoc bins at WalMart this morning.  The were advertised as weather tight.  Almost bought one myself.

Comment: are 5 gallon buckets big enough to store 50lbs of grain?

Comment: ~35lb for 5 gal paint bucket in my experience.